# unable to set android:windowBackground Error inflation on item requires drawable child

Tags: android, android-theme, android-inflate

In my application to avoid cold start I have defined a theme fro my splash activity  and set its `android:windowBackground` property to my one of drawables but I am getting an inflation error.

> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a
>   drawable

**background_splash.xml:**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**styles:**

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
    </style>
```

**Manifest:**

```
 <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the `background_splash.xml` file in this line.

```
 android:drawable="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
```

you have to change to this

```
android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

add your hex color code there and see the output.

Comment: drawable is not directly picking the color unless its defined in color values. :) rest is fine thansks

Comment: @MehvishFaisal glad to know that.